# How long are the number of views cached for search?

Tags: support, views

On Music, my most-viewed question has 698 views, but [searching for my questions with 694+ views](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A28+views%3A694) doesn't return any results; you have to go down to 693 or fewer.  The discrepancy is a little strange given that the search results show it with 698 views, but I figure there's some caching in play here.

However, I've noticed much greater discrepancies between the "actual" and "searchable" view counts before, and the numbers don't seem to update very quickly.  How long are the views cached for?  Do any events on the question trigger a cache update or is it a regular job or something?