# Is searching with view-filtering inaccurate by design?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, views

To my surprise, I figured out just now that [one of my questions on movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/where-are-frodo-gandalf-and-the-others-going-at-the-end-and-why) has a very high view-count. I wanted to see how many other questions on this site had a similar or higher view-count.

Therefore I search the site with `view:300000` as a search-words and I saw 6 other questions. Then I tried `view:350000` and it reduced to 3 questions and my question was not listed anymore.

However, my question has, at the time of writing this, 359966 views. It turns out that my questions enters the results again when using 324472 and disappears when using 324473.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125045/how-long-are-the-number-of-views-cached-for-search?rq=1

Comment: Also related, maybe duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283284/getting-questions-with-n-views-despite-searching-for-questions-with-%e2%89%a4n-views?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No bug here.

As explained in [the answer on a related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283285/152859):

> We do not reindex a post every time someone views it as that'd be pretty wasteful. As a consequence, older posts that had no activity in a while (voting, editing, etc.) will potentially have a rather out-of-sync value for views as far as search is concerned

Looking at the [question timeline](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/10037/timeline), the last activity was in May 22:

> [image]

So the views count indexed for search are the views back then, which is about [323,000 views](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A323000+is%3Aq).

When the question will get a new activity, the search index will be updated with the current view count.