# The question view count displayed in a search result page is inaccurate

Tags: bug, questions, search, views

Example from [android stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12202%20alarm): 7 views in search:

[image: IMG:]

vs. 168 views:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Maybe a caching thing?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125045/

Comment: Answer in comment on the dupe, TL;DR is that SE simply does not re-index questions for search when views change, or over time, so the amount of views in search results is the views when question was last indexed.